# Swift 5 conversion: FRadio code. "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

This is mentioned elsewhere on StackOverflow, but I can't find a recent example related to what's going on here. I converted to Swift 5, and this error comes up now.
There are lots of ideas around the actual error message, but nothing that gives me a clue to this. What am I missing here?

"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in this line of the code;

```
try? audioSession.setCategory(convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback), with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth])
```

In the code in the file FRadioPlayer.swift: which is on GitHub in fethica/FRadioPlayer.

```
    // MARK: - Initialization

private override init() {
    super.init()

    // Enable bluetooth playback
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try? audioSession.setCategory(convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback), with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth])
    // Notifications
    setupNotifications()

    // Check for headphones
    checkHeadphonesConnection(outputs: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs)

    // Reachability config
    try? reachability.startNotifier()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    isConnected = reachability.connection != .none
}
```

Comment: And if you do it piece by piece: `let var1: SomeClass = convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)`, `let var2 = [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth]` and finaly `try? audioSession.setCategory(var1, with: var2)`, which one is complaining?

Comment: I can't find the line you are talking about in the repo. I only found `try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: options)`.

Comment: You shouldn't be manually converting code from 3rd party frameworks to newer Swift versions. Only convert your own code and wait for framework maintainers to update their own code, then update the library version you use.

Comment: The convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory is crap generated by the converter. You need to get rid of it. You should not let the converter mangle your code like that.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I realized that I had made major changes to the code previously - some time ago. Just coming back to it and updated to Swift 5. So now replaced it with my original code and will NOT do the update. At least until I find out what's going on.